# Other ways to get a random number in Lua

Tags: random, lua

I'm looking for an alternative way to get a random number in Lua that is between a minimum and a maximum number without using `math.random()`. Is there any way? It doesn't have to be a simple method.

Comment: Why is `math.random` unsuitable? Have you tried searching for `lua random` online?

Comment: Perhaps you should give reason why you want to avoid random. Do you miss entropy ?

Comment: If you're running in Linux or Mac OS X, you can read bytes from `/dev/random` or`/dev/urandom`.

Comment: math.random() is not unsuitable, I am just wondering if there are other ways to get random numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the comments have hinted at, on Unix-like systems you can read bytes from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, and create a random number from them.

```
urand = assert (io.open ('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))
rand  = assert (io.open ('/dev/random', 'rb'))

function RNG (b, m, r)
  b = b or 4
  m = m or 256
  r = r or urand
  local n, s = 0, r:read (b)

  for i = 1, s:len () do
    n = m * n + s:byte (i)
  end

  return n
end
```

---

As an extension to this answer, and for fun, I've authored a very tiny module, [`randbytes`](https://github.com/okabsd/randbytes), so that future readers may play around with the `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` interfaces in a simple manner. Here's a quick run down.

Install with [`luarocks`](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks) or get it manually.

```
$ luarocks install randbytes
```

Require the module, or file.

```
$ lua
> randbytes = require 'randbytes'
```

And then grab some bytes.

```
> print (randbytes (8))
```

For now, I've cleaned up and included the very simple generation algorithm shown above, for generating basic random numbers.

```
> print (randbytes:urandom (16))
```

You can build on top of the basic interface to implement your own algorithms. Read the [documentation](https://github.com/okabsd/randbytes) for a full list of methods, and settings.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for!